# Is not loving what you love for yourself for your fellow Muslims a form of kufr (disbelief)?

Tags: kufr, behavior

“Love for the people what you love for yourself and you will be a believer.” [Sunan Ibn Mâjah]

If one is greedy and doesn't wish the best for others does that mean you are a disbeliever despite being a Muslim at the same time?

Because you know how if a person is stealing despite being Muslim that makes him following the non Muslim and non God fearing humans out there?

Does that mean if you are greedy it is a form of disbelief?

Answer (score 2):

The hadith you are talking about was narrated in both Bukhari and Muslim as follows:

> لايؤمن أحدكم حتى يحب لأخيه ما يحب لنفسه
> None of you [truly] believes until he loves for his brother what he
> loves for himself.

It doesn't mean that you will become a disbeliever if you don't love for your brother what you love for yourself, rather it means that your Imaan **is not going to be complete** if you don't have that quality.

Another narration of this Hadith in Musnad Al-Imam Ahmed:

> لا يبلغ العبد حقيقة الإيمان حتى يحب للناس ما يحب لنفسه
> The servant does not reach the reality of [or true] faith until he
> loves for the people what he loves for himself

For more information, check out this [link](http://en.islamway.net/article/13371/an-nawawis-forty-hadeeth-no-13)

Allah knows best!

Comment: What is going to happen if your imaan is not complete? Do you go to hell?

Comment: "rather it means that your Imaan is not going to be complete if you don't have that quality." - good said!

Comment: who said you are going to hell? why do you try to draw that conclusion?

Comment: @user15732 why are you fixated on "going to hell"?

Comment: That doesn't mean "going to hell". Everything has a level of quality, with being greedy, the level in heaven decreases.

Comment: I am scared to go there even for a second. I dont want to even look at it.